# Sort xml payload in Golang

Tags: go, aws-lambda

I have one project in aws lambda in Golang.
There we are using aws-api-gateway to accept rest api.
I wanted to sort the xml payload based on element coming from the user side.
But the problem is unmarshalling the xml payload is not allowed. I see somewhere that I can use xslt processor to sort the xml. But I’m unable to use this go package(github.com/wamuir/go-xslt) as it requires me to install some extra packages which is not in go. And our platform-team will not allowed it.
Is there any other go package that I can use.